# A question between the relation of the 1-alpha quantile and the 1-sqrt(alpha) quantile of the normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, quantiles

Can I show that
$$
P(Z\ge Z_{1-a} - C) > (P(Z\ge Z_{1-\sqrt\alpha}-C/\sqrt2))^2
$$
for every positive number $C$?

($Z_a$ is the quantile $a$ of the standard normal distribution.)

**What I Tried:**
In a simulation I couldn't disprove it. I wrote the function:
$$
f(C)=1-\Phi (Z_{1-a} - C) - (1 - \Phi (Z_{1-\sqrt a} - C/\sqrt2 )^2
$$
I need to show it's non negative for $C\ge0$).
It's obvious that $f(0)=0$, and that $lim_{C \rightarrow \infty}f(C)\rightarrow 0 $. By looking at the stimulation, the function has a minimum before 0, and a maximum after 0. The derivative with respect to C:
$$
f'(C)=\phi (z_{1-\alpha} -C)-\sqrt2(1-\Phi (Z_{1-\sqrt a} - c/\sqrt2))*\phi(Z_{i-\sqrt a}-C/\sqrt2)
$$
I got this far. By comparing the derivative to 0, I get something that I don't know how to solve. I also tried to substitute $x=0$ to check that the derviative is non-negative at this point (this is not enough for a solution but it's a start), and I got that it's positive if:
$$
-Z_{1-a}^2\ge-Z_{1-\sqrt a}^2+\ln2a
$$
But I don't know if it's always true.

Comment: This is an interesting question; I wonder if one might get somewhere with something related to Mills' Ratio, but I haven't really thought about it in any depth. In what context would such an issue arise? Or is it simply a mathematical curiosity?

Comment: The inequality is indeed true. The analysis is a little messy.  Making a contour plot of the difference as a function of $\log(\alpha) \le 1$ and $C$ for a wide range of $\log(\alpha)$ and $0\lt C\lt 6$ or so should be pretty convincing.  (In any event the difference approaches $0$ from above as $C$ grows large.)